# Is there a command that detects if a player has an effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a map and I need a command that detects when a player (preferably in a certain team) has an effect. The effect I will be detecting is STRENGTH 255. I already tried this command: `/execute if entity @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:5b, Amplifier: 255b}]}]`, and ran a comparator off of it, but it didn't seem to work. I also set the command block to repeat and always active. All feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

## Why Doesn’t it Work

Minecraft Java ActiveEffects tag is written as a byte, and values over 127 will wrap around to -127. This means that level 128 is actually -127. 255 is actually -1.

## Solution

Try this:

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:5b, Amplifier: -1b}]}]
```

Comment: Let’s just pretend I am smart and didn’t forget about that... *you saw nothing*